# XML and JSON result showing different result for common class in WEB API

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

In my WEB API i get the result in XML and Json. it works fine. But, When I collect data from DB some records is empty. While on conversion to xml or json, the result is different.
Common Class for Output is.

```
public  class items
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "frequency")]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "frequency")]
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "modulation")]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "modulation")]
    public string Modulation { get; set; }
}
```

Conversion takes place by

```
var Station = new items
{
    Frequency = (mContent["frequency"] is DBNull) ? null : mContent["frequency"].ToString(),
    Modulation = (mContent["modulation"] is DBNull) ? null : mContent["modulation"].ToString(),
}
```

For Json Result I get what I really want:

```
[{"items":[{"frequency":null,"modulation":null}]}]
```

The XML shows

```
<items>
  <item/>
</items>
```

But I want

```
 <items>
  <item>
    <frequency/>
    <modulation/>
 </item>
</items>
```

How could do this?

Comment: I would expect `<frequency/>` or `<frequency></frequency>` if the string is *present* but an empty string. The XML you're getting at the moment seems entirely reasonable for a null reference. Have you considered using `""` instead of `null` inside your object initializer?

Comment: That time Xml result is Correct, But for Json  shows "frequency":"","modulation":""

Comment: Well that's correct, for an empty string. Basically, there's no XML equivalent of `null`... you'd have to infer it from the lack of an element. (Or use xsi:nil - see my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to use the [`XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
public  class items
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "frequency")]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "frequency", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "modulation")]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "modulation", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Modulation { get; set; }
}
```

You should then get:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <frequency xsi:nil = "true" />
    <modulation xsi:nil = "true" />
 </item>
</items>
```

Comment: Sorry,, I have One more doubt, I get <modulation xmlns:d6p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d6p1:nil="true"/> how to remove Namespace, I am New to this. Thats why.

Comment: @SanjeevS: You shouldn't remove the namespace. That's basically `xsi:nil`, just using a different alias instead of `xsi`. There *may* be a way of specifying to use `xsi` everywhere, but I don't know where that would be... it shouldn't affect anything processing the XML though.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your time